# PHP 7 - password_hash returns NULL

Tags: php, php-7

So, this is a bit of a head scratcher for me. Server is Ubuntu with Apache 2.4, MySQL, and PHP 7.0.8 . I've read the docs, and searched Google and SO for possible answers with no luck. I have a basic function:

```
public function updatePassword($pw)
{
    $passwd = password_hash($pw, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    if($passwd !== NULL)
    {
        $this->sql = "UPDATE {$this->table} SET passwd='{$passwd}' WHERE id=".$_SESSION[PUBLIC_SITE]['uid'];
        $this->execSql("Updating User Password", UPDATE);
    }
}
```

`$passwd` is `NULL`, and I can't seem to figure out why. I've also tried setting the second argument to `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` and `password_hash` still returns `NULL`. What is the issue here? Have they not updated the docs to include mention of a new algorithm or something? Or am I missing something else here?

Comment: Errors enabled?  Debugging attempts?

Comment: yeah, answered my own question after reading the RFC. Passing an array to the function instead of a string. Deleting this momentarily. And grabbing another cup of coffee haha.

Comment: @TomJ Maybe consider answering yourself :)

Comment: Why consult a RFC instead of the documentation page for the function itself? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: @Kodos Johnson One reason is that the PHP docs don't mention returning NULL from password_hash, only false.  It's a well known problem in the PHP manual

Comment: That's where my confusion was coming from. Any other mentions of NULL being returned was a result of an invalid algorithm being passed for argument two, not an issue with the the first argument. 

It was a simple error I overlooked (more so related to my form handling, not the data itself). But the docs do not cover this condition. The RFC does (to a small extent).

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash, and being reminded of the error flags for debugging, I quickly realized I was passing an array to the function. `password_hash()` expects a string as the first argument. Resolved by passing the correct, expected input.